# Flow typing errors when dispatching actions

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm making some progress in reducing the Flow typing errors but am still stuck on one set of them.  Here's some sample code from my Actions file:

```
export const ADD_ERROR: 'ADD_ERROR' = 'ADD_ERROR';
export const CLEAR_ERRORS: 'CLEAR_ERRORS' = 'CLEAR_ERRORS';
export const TOGGLE_PROCESSING: 'TOGGLE_PROCESSING' = 'TOGGLE_PROCESSING';
export const RESET_STATE: 'RESET_STATE' = 'RESET_STATE';
export const CLEANUP_INPUT_COMPANY_INFO: 'CLEANUP_INPUT_COMPANY_INFO' = 'CLEANUP_INPUT_COMPANY_INFO';

type AddErrorAction = {type: typeof ADD_ERROR, payload: ValidationError};
type ClearErrorsAction = {type: typeof CLEAR_ERRORS};
type ToggleProcessingAction = {type: typeof TOGGLE_PROCESSING};
type ResetStateAction = {type: typeof RESET_STATE, userRole: Role | ''};
type CleanupInputCompanyInfoAction = {type: typeof CLEANUP_INPUT_COMPANY_INFO};

export type CustomerAction = 
     | AddErrorAction
     | ClearErrorsAction
     | ToggleProcessingAction
     | ResetStateAction
     | CleanupInputCompanyInfoAction;
```

Here is the companion Reducers file (abridged for clarity) :

```
import { ADD_ERROR,
         CLEAR_ERRORS,
         TOGGLE_PROCESSING
         RESET_STATE,
         CLEANUP_INPUT_COMPANY_INFO } from '../actions/Customer';

export const customerReducer = (state: CustomerState, action: CustomerAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ERROR: {
      return {
        // Code here
      };
    }

    case CLEAR_ERRORS: {
      return {
        // Code here
      };
    }

    case TOGGLE_PROCESSING: {
      return {
        // Code here
      };
    }

    case UPDATE_WIZARD_INDEX: {
      return {
        // Code here
      };
    }

    case RESET_STATE: {
      return {
        // Code here
      };
    }

    case CLEANUP_INPUT_COMPANY_INFO: {
      return {
        // Code here
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

There are no errors appearing in any of the code above ^^^.

In the associated Context is this code, which is built according to the approach outlined here: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from 'react';

import { customerReducer } from './reducers/Customer';
import type { CustomerAction } from './actions/Customer';
import type { UndefinedType } from '../redux/FlowTypes';
import type { ValidationError, User } from './SharedTypes';
import type { Role } from '../utils/constants';

type Dispatch = (action: CustomerAction) => void;

type CustomerState = {
  isProcessing: boolean,
  wizardIndex: number,
  validationErrors: (?ValidationError)[],
  companyName: string
};

const defaultState: FleetCustomerState = {
  isProcessing: false,
  wizardIndex: 0,
  validationErrors: [],
  companyName: ''
};

const CustomerStateContext = createContext<CustomerState>(defaultState);
const CustomerDispatchContext = createContext<Dispatch | UndefinedType>(undefined);

const CustomerProvider = ({ children }: {children: Object}) => {
  const [state: CustomerState, dispatch: Dispatch] = useReducer(customerReducer, defaultState);
  return (
    <CustomerDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <CustomerStateContext.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </CustomerStateContext.Provider>
    </CustomerDispatchContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useCustomerState = () => {
  const context = useContext(CustomerStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useCustomerState must be used within a CustomerProvider');
  }

  return context;
}

const useCustomerDispatch = () => {
  const context = useContext(CustomerDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useCustomerDispatch must be used within a CustomerProvider');
  }

  return context;
}

export type {CustomerState};
export {CustomerProvider, useCustomerState, useCustomerDispatch};
```

Then in my component, I dispatch like this:

```
dispatch({type: ADD_ERROR, payload: {name, message, id}});
dispatch({type: ADD_ERROR, payload: {name, message}});
dispatch({type: TOGGLE_PROCESSING});
dispatch({type: CLEAR_ERRORS});
```

And I get numerous errors with these `dispatch` statements.  The wording for each error is slightly different but has the same pattern.  Here are two examples:

> Cannot call `dispatch` with object literal bound to `action` because:
>   Either  string literal `TOGGLE_PROCESSING` [1] is incompatible with 
>   string literal `RESET_STATE` [2] in property `type`. Or  string
>   literal `TOGGLE_PROCESSING` [1] is incompatible with  string literal
>   `CLEANUP_INPUT_COMPANY_INFO` [3] in property `type`.
>
> Cannot call `dispatch` with object literal bound to `action` because:
>   Either  string literal `CLEAR_ERRORS` [1] is incompatible with  string
>   literal `RESET_STATE` [2] in property `type`. Or  string literal
>   `CLEAR_ERRORS` [1] is incompatible with  string literal
>   `CLEANUP_INPUT_COMPANY_INFO` [3] in property `type`.

I don't understand what to do with these error messages.  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the type for `dispatch`?

Comment: A link to http://flow.org/try would help a lot

Comment: @AlexSavin, thanks [as always] for your tremendous help!  There's so much code that putting it into flow.org/try would be very challenging but I have edited my post to show what's in the Context too.

Working Theory: Flow doesn't understand `switch ... case` statements in reducers.  What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to help if it's hard to reproduce. I can't reproduce the issue in the sandbox. And I even can't send you a link to the working sandbox in the comment because comments have limited length. If you will be able to provide a link to sandbox in your question it would be great. You need to reduce the problem to see the problem's root anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My best guesses:
- add action with type `UPDATE_WIZARD_INDEX` to `CustomerAction`
- make action annotation be exact. For example, instead of

`type AddErrorAction = {type: typeof ADD_ERROR, payload: ValidationError};`

try

`type AddErrorAction = {|type: typeof ADD_ERROR, payload: ValidationError|};`
for all actions

Comment: What does the pipe character (`|`) before `type` and after `ValidationError}` do?

Comment: Found it: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types

Note: You put the 2nd pipe character in the wrong place.

Comment: I hadn't revisited this question in a while.  The problem turned out to be that I had moved some of my Actions to a "common" file - ie. containing those that were shared by more than one reducer.  This causes problems for Flow so now there is a 1-to-1 relationship between Actions file and Reducers file and all of the errors related to this disappeared.